# Cannot read property of undefined inside find function

Tags: javascript, angular

I am using javascripts `.find()` function to return an object if a value exists however I get an undefined error

```
this.reduceoptionRadio = 'instalment'
this.calculatorResult = 
[
    {
        "newCalculatedInstallmentsNo": "50",
        "newContractEndDate": "20250701",
        "newResidual": "0",
        "newInstalment": "4071.91",
        "newTerm": "52",
        "outBalanceAvaf": null,
        "restructureType": "term"
    },
    {
        "newCalculatedInstallmentsNo": "52",
        "newContractEndDate": "20250901",
        "newResidual": "0",
        "newInstalment": "3939.93",
        "newTerm": "54",
        "outBalanceAvaf": null,
        "restructureType": "instalment"
    }
]



this.calculateFormData = this.calculatorResult.find(
  function(el) {
  return el.restructureType === this.reduceoptionRadio;
  }
);
console.log(this.calculateFormData);
```

How can I get the value of `this.reduceoptionRadio` to reflect with the find function? The value of `this.reduceoptionRadio` is dynamic, I just hardcoded here so I can have relevant code to explain.

Exact error in console reads `ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'reduceoptionRadio' of undefined`

Comment: Inside of 'find' try to use an arrow function. It will resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The ES5 syntax of a function `function(el)` creates a new context (a new `this`). Inside it, `this` refers to the function itself, where `reduceoptionRadio` is logically undefined.

An old (pre-ES6) and dirty workaround used to be :

```
var self = this;

this.calculateFormData = this.calculatorResult.find(
  function(el) {
      return el.restructureType === self.reduceoptionRadio;
  }
);
```

Instead, use the newer ES6 "fat arrow" syntax, which passes the context (`this`) inside the function :

```
this.calculateFormData = this.calculatorResult.find( el => el.restructureType === this.reduceoptionRadio );
```

Comment: when I try the ES6 version I get the `this.calculateFormData` as undefined if I console.log it
`this.calculateFormData = this.calculatorResult.find( el => el.restructureType === this.reduceoptionRadio );`
`console.log(this.calculateFormData);`

Comment: @skydev not reproducible: https://jsfiddle.net/q0j1o3nt/ . Is the array populated asynchronously?

Comment: @adiga yes it is populated asynchronously. It works with flat data but not asynchronously

Comment: @skydev you need to do `this.calculatorResult.find` after the array is populated.

Comment: Of course, if you try to find things in an array that's not yet populated, you won't find anything :)